Service is not getting recognized by service registry(Eureka)
I am encountering the error, that my service is not getting recognized in eureka hence and able to called the info from other service.
I have 3 services: User, Product and Tax. all of these have userId, productId and taxId in them. each unique to them and only created in their own service.
Now I am trying to display data for all users, where they can have multiple properties but each property have only single tax related to it. So I have created everything according to it.
It my previous post which I have updated accordingly to needs :
text
Adding only edited parts, my UserServiceImpl
    @Override
    public List<UserDto> getUser() {
        
        List<Users> users = this.userRepository.findAll();
        
        //Hotel hotel = hotelService.getHotel(rating.getHotelId());

        
        List<UserDto> userDtos = users.stream().map(user -> {
                    UserDto userDto = this.usersTouserDto(user);
                    
                    // Fetching properties for this user using property_ID
                        List<PropertyDto> propertyDtos = this.property_service.getPropertyById(user.getPropertyId());
                        
                        logger.info("Info of Property ID : ", propertyDtos);
                        userDto.setPropertiesDto(propertyDtos); // Set properties in UserDto

                        
                    // Fetch tax data for each property
                        List<TaxDto> taxDtos = propertyDtos.stream().map(property -> {
                            return this.tax_service.getTaxById(property.getTaxId());
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

                        logger.info("Info of Property ID : ", taxDtos);
                        userDto.setTaxesDto(taxDtos);  // Set taxes in UserDto  
                        
                    
                    return userDto;             //returning the value
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return userDtos;
    }

and my Property_Management_Service, I am no longer using my ResponseEntity in my Feign interfaces.
@FeignClient(name = "property-data-management")
public interface Property_Management_Service {

    
    // list all property data by property id
    @GetMapping("api/property/v1/property/{propertyId}")
    List<PropertyDto> getPropertyById(@PathVariable String propertyId);
}

now when I am trying to run user api in my postman, I am getting the error of
{
    "timestamp": "2024-09-28T07:08:17.287+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "feign.RetryableException: Connect timed out executing GET http://property-data-management/api/property/v1/property/78jk538sf55\r\n\tat feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:278)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:110)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:70)\r\n\tat feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:99)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy167.getPropertyById(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.user_dm.UM.services.UserServiceImpl.lambda$0(UserServiceImpl.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)\r\n\tat com.user_dm.UM.services.UserServiceImpl.getUser(UserServiceImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat com.user_dm.UM.controllers.UserController.getAllUsers(UserController.java:45)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\r\nCaused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:636)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:280)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:386)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:408)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1304)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1237)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1123)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1052)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1599)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:531)\r\n\tat feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:111)\r\n\tat feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerUtils.executeWithLoadBalancerLifecycleProcessing(LoadBalancerUtils.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerUtils.executeWithLoadBalancerLifecycleProcessing(LoadBalancerUtils.java:91)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:134)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:100)\r\n\t... 61 more\r\n",
    "message": "Connect timed out executing GET http://property-data-management/api/property/v1/property/78jk538sf55",
    "path": "/api/user/v1/users"
}

I have checked a lot and it says its due to my service not getting registered in my eureka.
But when do localhost:8761/eureka, I can clearly see

for my :::: 192.168.1.44:User-Data-Management:8082
192.168.1.44 I have made server.address as 0.0.0.0 in my application property file.
And even when I am individually hitting the api in postman I am getting correct response.

It seems the issue lies in my DNS resolution or network configuration
